# Mat-Menu Items not Dynamically Showing on *ngFor Condition (Angular)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, angular-material

In my angular application, I am using two JSON arrays to dynamically create a menu.

For some reason when I add the second `*ngFor` condition, I am unable to reach the items necessary in order to show the items in the menu.

`{{function}}` is the items that should be showing dynamically in the menu. and action is a set of json values that are passed through a function in order for a click event function to work.

When I remove the `ngFor="let action of action` line I'm able to see the items but I need the action value in order to make the click event work on the button.

What am I doing wrong here?

**view.component.html**

```
<mat-menu #contextMenu="matMenu" #contextMenu2="matMenu">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let funct of FunctionNames">
    <div mat-menu-item>
      <div matMenuContent *ngFor="let act of action;">
        <button mat-menu-item (click)="onContextMenuAction(act )">{{funct}}</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</mat-menu>
```

**view.component.ts**

```
  onContextMenu(event: MouseEvent, action: ViewDataSource) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.contextMenuPosition.x = event.clientX + 'px';
    this.contextMenuPosition.y = event.clientY + 'px';
    this.contextMenu.menuData = { action: action };
    this.contextMenu.menu.focusFirstItem('mouse');
    this.contextMenu.openMenu();
  }

  onContextMenuAction(action: ViewDataSource) {
    console.log(action);
    console.log('clicked');
  }
```

**the JSON values looks like this for each array:**

```
functionName = ["value1", "value2", "value3" ....]
action = [value: 0, value1: 1, value2: 2 .... etc]
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the issue is, but I would strongly recommend that you do not re-use variable names and that you don't use reserved words for variable names.  So rename the variable `function` as that is a reserved word and change the variable name `let action of action` to something else like `let act of action`

Comment: i just updated the variable names, thank you for that. My issue is that the second ngfor loop is not being reached for some reason, and is causing my menu to not function properly. If I remove the second ngFor then the items show, but I need the action object to pass through to my click function in order for my menu to be functional @ChrisG